# Matplotlib Colormap Same Color

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

I have created a barplot in matplotlib from a pandas series that looks like this:[image: Barplot]

As you can see, the two grey colors are too similar. [Set1](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) looks to have a good number of colors so how come it is repeating them for a grouped bar plot of only 4 categories per group? Below is my code:

```
ax = df.groupby([
    'type',
    'effect'
]).size().reset_index().pivot(index='type', columns='effect', values=0).plot(
    kind='bar',
    colormap=plt.cm.Set1
)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3,1))
```

I can get around it by setting `color=plt.cm.Set1(np.linspace(0,1,6))` and removing the colormap from my plot call, but this seems kind of hacky... mainly because I have to choose the number 6 manually to make it look good. The colormap should be able to infer the number of colors to use and which ones to use. Is there a way to do this?

Here is some code for a minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'effect_1': pd.Series([1379], index=['type_1']),
    'effect_2': pd.Series([1666], index=['type_1']),
    'effect_3': pd.Series([197], index=['type_1']),
    'effect_4': pd.Series([166], index=['type_1']),
})
test.plot(kind='bar', colormap='Set1')
```

The example code should yield this figure:
[image: Example code generated figure]

Comment: That seems strange. However I cannot reproduce the issue without a [mcve].

Comment: I'll write some code for one such group and will post it shortly

Comment: Posted and example, see question

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? In my case mpl.__version__ is 2.0.0. I get red, purple, brown and grey.

Comment: I got the same as @PabloReyes.

Comment: [This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhoXx.png) I get with your code. Seems correct to me. Even in your case, the second color is not really gray but some other color, so you might just want to choose a different colormap.

Comment: I'm using matplotlib version 1.5.3. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest using another colormap is also not a real solution. If you want to be consistent across figures for example. Also Set1 clearly has several different colors to choose from, I understand the colors are actually different, but they do look very similar and they shouldn't given that this is a sequential colormap

Comment: Most likely version 1.5.3 considers the Qualitative colormaps still as `LinearSegmentedColormaps`, instead of `ListedColormaps`. See: https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#qualitative-colormaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen from the [colormaps page of matplotlib version 1.5.3](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), the `Set1` colormap looks like this:

[image]

As can be seen there is some gray color in between green and purple, as well as at the far end of the colormap. So the plot you get is expected for this colormap.

You may want to upgrade your matplotlib if the use of the new `Set1` is important, otherwise you may just want to choose a different colormap.